# Execute foreign functions using FDWs in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-fdw

Is it possible to execute functions that are located on a foreign server using `postgres_fdw`? If not, is there any available workaround?

Comment: I think [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html) is your only option for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the function in a view on the foreign side, then map a foreign table onto that view.  This isn't very flexible as you can't specify the arguments to the function--either it must take no arguments, or they must be specified at the time the view is created.

Or, you can use dblink to execute arbitrary SQL on a foreign PostgreSQL server.  This is pretty annoying, but if you already have a foreign server defined using postgres_fdw, you can at least give dblink's functions the name of that server rather than needing to give them a connection string.